# PL/SQL use read varaibles

Tags: sql, plsql

I have to read some string subset to check if any name in Users (my table) contains that subset.

```
   DECLARE
   numberOf_studs users.name%type;
BEGIN   
   SELECT count(name) INTO numberOf_studs FROM users where replace(name,&name,'#')<>name ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of studs: ' || numberOf_studs);
END;
```

That's what I'm trying to do, but I got some errors in using &name for reading input.

Comment: Checking to see if a string contains a substring is much simpler than what you are doing. For example, the `where` condition may be `where name like '%' || '&name' || '%'` (That string can be written also as `'%name%'`, but I find that version harder to read.)

Comment: Yup, it really is simpler that way. I just took the first idea I had; Probably I thought it cannot be  that easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think you intended this:

```
DECLARE
   numberOf_studs int;
BEGIN   
   SELECT count(name) INTO numberOf_studs FROM users where replace(name,'&name','#')<>name ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of studs: ' || numberOf_studs);
END;
/
```

Things I changed:

- `&name` to `'&name'` as entered value will (probably) be some text value
- `numberOf_studs` datetype to `int` as count will be a numeric value